# Rar downloaded shows unexpected end of archive error

Tags: php

I want to stream remote file to user via php script.
Now I have  2 function.

```
function dl_file_resumable($file, $is_resume=TRUE, $type, $name, $length, $header)
{


    //Gather relevent info about file
    $size = remotefilesize($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);

    //workaround for IE filename bug with multiple periods / multiple dots in filename
    //that adds square brackets to filename - eg. setup.abc.exe becomes setup[1].abc.exe
    $filename = (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) ? preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileinfo['basename'], substr_count($fileinfo['basename'], '.') - 1) : $fileinfo['basename'];


    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);

        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
    }

    //figure out download piece from range (if set)
    list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs

(intval($seek_start)),0);

    //add headers if resumable
    if ($is_resume)
    {
        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$size);
    }

    //headers for IE Bugs (is this necessary?)
    //header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");   
    //header("Pragma: public");

    header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
   header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
    //header('Content-Length: '.$length);

    //open the file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    //seek to start of missing part
    fseek($fp, $seek_start);

    //start buffered download
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        //reset time limit for big files
        set_time_limit(0);
        print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

and

```
function remotefilesize($url, $user = "", $pw = "")
{
    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

    if(!empty($user) && !empty($pw))
    {
        $headers = array('Authorization: Basic ' .  base64_encode("$user:$pw"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    $ok = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $head = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $regex = '/Content-Length:\s([0-9].+?)\s/';
    $count = preg_match($regex, $head, $matches);

    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : "unknown";
}
```

I got this code by googling and modified it a little bit.
the problem is, I tried this script with remote rar file. But when the rar file downloaded, it shows error when Im tring to open it. "Unexpected end of archive".
Whats wrong with this script??

I am not expert in php, so I need clear answer from you. All help will be appreciate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!!
actually, in my real code, there is an echo in `dl_file_resumable` function..
this will result the echo being attach in downloaded file and change the size and the code of file.. I detect this problem using hex editor and saw the echo text exists in my rar source code..

Comment: Your answer came like a sign from the heavens after 1-2 hours of not figuring out what's wrong. I had some *echo*'s and *print_r*'s before using *readfile()*. Thanks!